# How to access all items through fromJSON array in github-action?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions

I am using [docker/metada-action](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action). How should I access all the items in the tags array?
I can able to access the first item like `"${{fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).tags[0]}}"` but could not find a way to access all items in the array.

I tried numerous ways like the below and also but did not work. `fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).tags['*']`,`fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).tags[@]`

What is the best way of achieving this?

```
   - name: Push Image
      if: ${{ inputs.registry }}
      run: |
        for tag in ${{ fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).tags[0] }}
        do
          echo tag
        done
      shell: bash
```

Here is the output

```
JSON output
  {
    "tags": [
      "azurecr.io/internal/dx-integration-bootstrap:feature-docker-action-bootstrap",
      "azurecr.io/internal/dx-integration-bootstrap:sha-e3416c8"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did via using join method.

```
- name: Push Image
  if: ${{ inputs.registry }}
  run: |
    for tag in ${{ join(fromJSON(steps.meta.outputs.json).tags, ' ') }}
    do
      echo "Pushing image $tag"
      docker push $tag
    done
  shell: bash
```